# ELK, File beat cut some text from message

Tags: elastic-stack, filebeat

I have ELK(filebeat->logstash->elasticsearch<-kibana) running on win10. I gave the following two lines, then I found filebeat not sending whole text, rather some head/front texts are cut.

```
2018-04-27 10:42:49 [http-nio-8088-exec-1] - INFO  - app-info - injectip ip 192.168.16.89
2018-04-27 10:42:23 [RMI TCP Connection(10)-127.0.0.1] - INFO  - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

In filebeat console, I notice following text:

```
2018-05-24T09:02:50.361+0800    DEBUG   [publish]       pipeline/processor.go:275       Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2018-05-24T01:02:50.361Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.2.3"
  },
  "source": "e:\\sjj\\xxx\\YKT\\ELK\\twoFormats.log",
  "offset": 97083,
  "message": "xec-1] - INFO  - app-info - injectip ip 192.168.16.89",
  "prospector": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "beat": {
    "name": "DESKTOP-M4AFV3I",
    "hostname": "DESKTOP-M4AFV3I",
    "version": "6.2.3"
  }
}
```

and

```
2018-05-24T09:11:10.374+0800    DEBUG   [publish]       pipeline/processor.go:275       Publish event: {
  "@timestamp": "2018-05-24T01:11:10.373Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.2.3"
  },
  "prospector": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "beat": {
    "version": "6.2.3",
    "name": "DESKTOP-M4AFV3I",
    "hostname": "DESKTOP-M4AFV3I"
  },
  "source": "e:\\sjj\\xxx\\YKT\\ELK\\twoFormats.log",
  "offset": 97272,
  "message": "n(10)-127.0.0.1] - INFO  - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'"
}
```

In the console, one could see message part, some front text is cut off. In first case, '2018-04-27 10:42:49 [http-nio-8088-e' is cut, in the second case, '2018-04-27 10:42:23 [RMI TCP Connectio' is cut.

Why filebeat will do this? this makes my regex generates parserexception in logstash.

I list my filebeat.yml file as follows:

```
#=========================== Filebeat prospectors =============================

filebeat.prospectors:

# Each - is a prospector. Most options can be set at the prospector level, so
# you can use different prospectors for various configurations.
# Below are the prospector specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this prospector configuration.
  #enabled: false
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    #- /var/log/*.log
    - e:\sjj\xxx\YKT\ELK\twoFormats.log


  ### Multiline options

  # Mutiline can be used for log messages spanning multiple lines. This is common
  # for Java Stack Traces or C-Line Continuation

  # The regexp Pattern that has to be matched. The example pattern matches all lines starting with [
  multiline.pattern: '^[[:space:]]'

  multiline.negate: false

  multiline.match: after


#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
  #index.codec: best_compression
  #_source.enabled: false


#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```